# Project stopped working after downgrading Rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Initially i was using rails version 5.1.1, but when i downgraded it to 4.2.7 then it started giving me the following error:

```
`method_missing': undefined method `load_defaults'
```

whenever i try to run "rails s" it shows the above error in terminal, it is just a fresh project, i just installed a new project by using "rails new ", then i changed the rails version in gem file to

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.7'
```

then after doing this when i tried to hit "rails s" it started giving me that error.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: According to [RailsDiff](http://railsdiff.org/4.2.7/5.1.1) fresh Rails applications in Version `4.2.7` and `5.1.1` have quite different a structure and file contents. Why do you expect that an application that was generated with the latest version can be run with a version that is almost a year old?

Comment: Just regenerate the app.

Comment: I wonder how this ...uhhhhm question got 2 upvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Rails application generated with version 5.1.1 includes this line:

```
# in config/application.rb:12
config.load_defaults 5.1
```

`load_defaults` is a method that was introduced in Rails 5 and does not exist in Rails 4.2.x

That said, you cannot just downgrade a Rails version (btw you usually cannot just upgrade either). You need to change your application to the structure the other Rails version is expecting. [RailsDiff](http://railsdiff.org/) is a great resource to see the differences between applications generated with different versions of Rails.

You have two options:

1. Adopt the changes between the versions or
2. Regenerate a new application with the desired version.